# Given a query, how do I find the ORM method that generated it?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

We're using both Cake and Symfony where I work, as well as the Doctrine ORM, across multiple projects. Very few places in our codebase has actual SQL queries written out in the code - we're letting the ORM libraries do the heavy lifting.

Now my IT guy gives me 100mb file from the MySQL slow query log and I need to find where this query is getting created. I've tried various recursive greps in the codebase for specific fields and coming up either with dozens if not hundreds of files, or empty handed. For example:

```
cd ~/webproject
grep -r -E 'field1.*field2.*field3' .
```

or

```
find . -name '*.php' -print | xargs grep -E 'field1.*field2.*field3'
```

Do you have any better recommendations, tricks or techniques you use to track down the files, controllers or ORM model methods that correlate to a particular final "rendered" SQL statement?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a trick you can use. I'm not familiar with Doctrine or the Cake ORM, but it can be easily described in general terms - I use Propel, and I'm sure it can do this.

Simply add a custom `WHERE` clause to all your queries, as follows (swapping out the method name for your own, as appropriate). The `1 = 1` is effectively a no-op, and should not in itself affect query performance, and will allow you to smuggle in a handy comment:

```
$query->addCustomWhere(
    '1 = 1 /* ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . ' */'
);
```

Then all your logged queries will have the class/function next to them, in a comment. Of course, you can write a helper method for this, just passing in the query and the magic variables, to save having to write it out each time.

Comment: This is actually a pretty nice trick for development environments, but unfortunately I am not going to be allowed to deploy code comments inside SQL to my production server. This kind of a "trick" would never pass code review where I work. I was hoping to find the model method somehow searching the codebase.

Comment: @phpguru: not being allowed to comment code is ludicrous, in my view. The whole point of this is to add a record of what is happening in production (i.e. keep it permanently). Any "review" that refuses it is, I think, missing the point of code review.

Comment: I agree in some sense it is ludicrous. That said, if you work in a PCI compliant code shop where every line is scrupulously reviewed by auditors and/or your servers are under constant heavy load while trimming storage space, replication bandwidth and costs is the primary goal, you have limited options. What you propose changes production processes and that is often not allowed. Imagine 1TB/day of replication logs increasing to 1.25TB/day and try to justify it to the board. That help? I need to inspect code, not logs.

Comment: Sounds like your hands are somewhat tied, @phpguru. Personally I'd try filtering the logs (or creating a second log stream) so that no more than a few hours of appended comments are kept (or however long is takes to reliably wait for the slow query to occur). That will keep your log growth static. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a magic search approach, other than the obvious: examine the query and guess what finder clauses would have been used. Sorry!